# Unable to mention user in a comments section

Tags: discussion, comments, users

Pretty primitive user story:

Me, as topic starter asked a question. After a few moments, i receive answer, which isn't complete and requires a few more explanation. I click on 'add comments ' and trying to type '@user' so he could see my answer. But, multiple issues occur:

1. i'm unable to mention ( i tried with all known features, no luck),
   so it ends with a recognition as plain text, not a link to user
   profile.
2. On submit my '@user' (or any other attempt to mention) gets removed,
   so i assume user couldn't be notified. Is this an issue, or I'm
   doing something wrong on mentioning?

Thanks for explanation

P.S if my username gets notified in a comments section, I get notification for that. But I can't mention him in a reply(issue?).

Comment: I'm confused on how you couldn't reply to them (maybe link to what you are talking about) but if it was on an answer then the poster of that answer will get a notification when you comment on the answer.

Comment: @codeMagic oh, now i can mention you. Typical situation. i tried two times to mention user, but failure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416572/design-layout-issue/41417636#41417636

all attempts to mention were removed on submit

Comment: OK, ya you don't need it in that case since they will be notified so it doesn't show

Comment: @codeMagic unfortunately, i need to inform them that i've updated question/comment. Thats a problem. Since they not notified about that, they could not predict that I tried to talk to them.

Comment: Read my original comment and the link posted as a duplicate. The answerer will be notified when you comment on their post.